# How to remove sites word from URL

Tags: sharepoint-server

How to remove **sites word** from this URL http://Soial/**sites**/test/EN/

Comment: Can;t remove it, but replace it with your word for new site collection

Comment: Create site at root of site collection. Then sites keyword will not display in URL. Otherwise you need to use Managed path. Check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc261845.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things, you can do.

1. **HNSC**: if you want to remove the sites from your site collection URL then you have to think about the Host Name Site Collection, this way you can define a new URL i.e http://test.com. Please read more [about it here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx)
2. Another option changes the **Sites** with something else but you can't remove it. Even as the explicit wildcard you can't remove it as only one root level site collection is allowed at "/". MSFT also recommend "Do not use “/*” to indicate wildcard managed sites at the root of the site collection."

Answer (score 0):

To don't have 'sites' in the url for site collection you would have to create explicit managed path. But beware there are performance issues if you have to many managed paths. Have a look at this article for more info: https://bp.spdockit.com/article/sharepoint-software-boundaries-and-limits/limits-by-hierarchy/web-application-limits/managed-paths/